# Como pasar un String de un metodo a otro

Tags: java, android

Lo siento soy novato en esto, necesito pasar un string de un metodo a otro

El string que trato de pasar se llama (bd_lat)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

String bd_lat = object.getString("latitude");

}
```

este es el metodo donde lo debo pasar

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

LatLng Bello = new LatLng(PONER ACA STRING bd_lat, -75.5580);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea el String bd_lat como variable Global. Para hacer esto basta con declarar la variable fuera del metodo onCreate así:

```
Double bd_lat;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    bd_lat = Double.parseDouble(object.getString("latitude"));
}

@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

LatLng Bello = new LatLng(bd_lat, -75.5580);

}
```

Así la podes usar donde quieras dentro de esa clase.

Comment: Excelente, pero sabes, en los maps no me esta leyendo la latitud, la puse asi: LatLng location= new LatLng(bd_lat, bd_lng);

Comment: Exactamente a que llamas no me esta leyendo? no se invoca el método ready? o se invoca pero te sale un error?

Comment: Si claro mira me muestra un error que dice: LatLng (double, double ) in LatLng cannot be applied.

Comment: Ok, lo que pasa es que tienes que convertir bd_lat a double, te voy a corregir la respuesta para que funcione.

Comment: Voiy a probar, muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda ya te digo

Comment: que pena molestarte tanto, la app corre pero se cierra, y me muestra esto: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.elgeos.school, PID: 29745
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
                      at com.elgeos.school.MapsTracker.onMapReady(MapsTracker.java:146), que equivale a la linea: LatLng Bello = new LatLng(bd_lat, -75.5580);

Comment: Lo que pasa e que bd_lat esta nula y como se esta tratando de convertir a un Double saca ese error. Lo mejor es que mires la linea que tiene object.getString("latitude") porque esa sentencia te esta devolviendo null como valor.